# Proving the following inequality in a triangle

Tags: triangles

In a triangle the straight lines $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are drawn through a point $P$ to meet $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ at $D$, $E$, $F$ respectively:

[image]

Prove that $$\frac{PD}{AD} + \frac{PE}{BE}+\frac{PF}{CF}=1$$ and $$\frac{AP}{AD}+ \frac{BP}{BE}+\frac{CP}{CF}=2$$

Comment: Can we have a diagram? Or an explanation as to what these are. Is this a Triangle ABC with midpoints D,E,F?

Comment: I have made an edit.

Comment: Are D,E,F arbitrary? Or are they midpoints? If they are midpoints, then you can use the properties of centroid to say 1/3+1/3+1/3=1

Comment: If it was so easy I could have easily solved it and D, E, F are arbitrary points

Comment: It's rather $P$ is arbitrary inside $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: P is arbitrary therefore D, E, F are arbitrary.

Comment: Not to picky, but $D,E,F$ are arbitrary *so that $AD,BE,$ and $CF$ meet at one point $P$*. That condition kills the *arbitrary* of $D,E,F$.

Comment: I mean that D, E, F change according to P.

Comment: Fix the title please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $G$ and $H$ on $AC$ so that $PG\parallel AB$ and $PH\parallel BC$. It follows that
$$\frac{FP}{FC}=\frac{AG}{AC}, \frac{PD}{PA}=\frac{HC}{AC}.$$
Now we only need to show 
$$\frac{PE}{BE}=\frac{GH}{AC}.$$
But this follows from the fact that
$$\frac{PE}{BE}=\frac{EG}{EA}=\frac{EH}{EC}=\frac{GE+EH}{AE+EC}.$$

Comment: How did you come together conclusion that PE/BE=EG/EA

Comment: Look at $\triangle EAB$ with $PG\parallel AB$.

Comment: Got it thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{PD}{AD}$ is equal to $\dfrac{\mathrm{Area}\, BPC}{\mathrm{Area}\, ABC}$, and similarly for the other two ratios. Now just add them up. This gives you the first equation.

The second equation is simple arithmetic: $AP+PD=AD$, so $\dfrac{AP}{AD} = 1 - \dfrac{PD}{AD}$, and simliarly for the other two ratios. Now just add them up again.